# C# what is the risk of calling an async method and never awaiting the returned task or storing references to said Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception, async-await, task

I know that exception handling can become strange if you never await a returned Task, but if you don't actually care about the results and/or the success of the async method, does it matter if you don't store a reference to the task anywhere? Basically I just want to fire and forget the method, and I want to know how pedantic I need to be when doing so.

My specific use case is an async dispose method, which waits for any outstanding tasks to finish running before it disposes any HTTPClients.

```
public async Task Dispose(){
    try{
        ...
    }catch{} //might add some minimal logging, but probably wont
}
```

In descending order of laziness, the implementations I've been considering are

```
public void DisposeFoo(){
   foo.Dispose()//feed the task to the void
}
```

is the above any more or less safe than

```
private Task DisposeFooTask;
public void DisposeFoo(){
   DisposeFooTask= foo.Dispose()//store the task and never touch it again
}
```

And I also found this approach on SO

```
static async void FireAndForget(this Task task)
{
   try
   {
        await task;
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
       // log errors
   }
}
public void DisposeFoo(){
   foo.Dispose().FireAndForget();
}
```

Is there any risk of an error in foo.Dispose() escaping any try catches and killing my system if I ignore the Task? And if not, is there any risk of something like the thread running foo.Dispose() giving up on life due to the task not being in scope anymore? Or is the danger with my lazy coding purely exception hiding?

Comment: If you use IHttpClientFactory, there is no need to dispose, the new implementation cleans up all the resources. Secondly it doesn't matter if you don't await, you just need be mindful of the errors

Comment: The exception to this rule is if you read only the headers of the response using `HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead`, in which case the response is not buffered and will need to be disposed

Comment: In regards to IHttpClientFactory if all this is in the one method group, just use a using where you normally would (no harm done), catch and log any errors, and discard. Or if you like create an async void FireAndForget Method, that catches and discards, other then that there is not really much more to talk about

Comment: If you don't care whether `foo.Dispose()` throws or not, that why do you care about whether the `foo` is disposed or not? Just omit disposing it altogether. What's the worst that could happen?

Comment: Thanks for being so helpful Sir General, my use case is a client object that gets used everywhere - infrequently something will happen that will supply our service with new API definitions (possibly several), That's why I wanted to half heartedly dispose of any resources on the old ones and why using statements aren't really an option

Comment: Your answer was everything I needed though, I'll stick with the lazy approach, thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if you don't actually care about the results and/or the success of the async method, does it matter if you don't store a reference to the task anywhere?

A task will generally not be eligible for garbage collection until it completes; this is because there is some kind of callback (that will complete the task) that references that task, and those callbacks are generally rooted (in GC terms).

When a task is ignored (i.e., completed but not observed), then it can become eligible for garbage collection. If that task completes with an exception, then it will raise `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` when it is GC'ed. This event *used* to crash the process but no longer does.

If you want to avoid raising the event completely, then you can use the `FireAndForget` wrapper to explicitly observe and ignore the exception.

However, the **primary problem with fire-and-forget tasks** is that your code cannot know when the task completes. Which is the whole *point* of fire-*and-forget* tasks, but it's amazing how many people think they want "fire-and-forget" but then want to ensure that the tasks complete. This is a common problem when determining when it is safe to exit the process.

> My specific use case is an async dispose method, which waits for any outstanding tasks to finish running before it disposes any HTTPClients.

Calling dispose as a fire-and-forget task would be OK. Shutdown isn't a consideration in this case, since the OS will clean up anyway.

However, calling dispose in a task at all is kind of odd. Disposal is usually extremely fast (like literally setting a field or two), so it doesn't make sense to push that work to a background thread.

Comment: It's because I'm waiting for any outstanding calls to finish before disposing the actual httpClient and cancelling the tokenSource, but it's also something I've been curious about for a while now

Comment: If you're *also* fire-and-forgetting those API calls themselves, then you should be aware that they can be cancelled when your application exits. So by making them fire-and-forget, you are declaring that you don't care if they complete. Which seems much more dangerous to me.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any risk of an error in foo.Dispose() escaping any try catches and killing my system if I ignore the Task?

There are uncatchable errors, but these would close the process even if you tried to handle the errors from the task. So in practice the task should always complete.

> And if not, is there any risk of something like the thread running foo.Dispose() giving up on life due to the task not being in scope anymore?

No, the task would be referenced by a taskscheduler, and this would keep it alive until it can be started. And once it is running it is kept alive by the thread running it.

> Or is the danger with my lazy coding purely exception hiding?

Yes, as far as I can tell the worst effect would be to hide potential exceptions.